# Group Excel Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tough one (atleast for me). I am trying to group similar data in Excel. Below is a picture of what I am looking at and an explanation of what I am trying to do:

[image]

- The Value's across the top are the values for each zone.
- The letters down the left side are different variables for each zone.
- Some variables go that specific zone and some do not.

For instance "A" goes to All of the zones as does "C". "B" however only goes to zones 1, 1A, and 2.

I am needing for Excel to split these and list which "variables" (Column A) and final value totals for each different group of variables.

So "A and B" would be a total of 29,483 as they go into all of the zones, and then it would also list "A,B,C" and a total of 25,651 since that only goes into Zone 1, 1A, and 2.

I am needing those listed together in a easy to view table.

Comment: Hi there!  We're not a free script/formula writing service.  Please include where you're getting stuck, what you've tried already, and what the results of those trials were.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghnbe4ghj8fwbpq/Group%20Excel%20Values.xlsx?dl=0).